# clickTAG doesn't fire in FancyBox when scripted with AS3

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, fancybox

I work for an internet media company.  We use fancybox to load the ever-infamous "roadblock" ad placement.

When we load ads that have a clickTAG scripted in ActionScript 3, FancyBox fails to initiate the click. Yet, clickTAGs done is AS2 work just fine. We've tested this issue in ad placements that do not require the use of FancyBox and everything checks out.  Both placements (regular site placements and FancyBox) use the Javascript, "onclick" event, but also have standard embed parameters (`<object>xxx</object>`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try setting flashVars in the html and then grabbing them like this:

```
function onSomethingClicked():void
{
    var req:String;

    if ((req = root.loaderInfo.parameters.clickTag))
    {
        openWindow(req);
    }

}

function openWindow(req:String):void
{
    // 
}
```

EDIT:  After looking at Fancybox I'm not sure if this will help but I'll leave it here just in case.